# What is wrong with my Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I have a brand new laptop, Intel Core i5 CPU, 8 GB ram, running 64-bit Windows 7.  It came with IE 9, which locked up 50% of the time.

I eliminated Silverlight, thinking that could cause some problems. Tried a few other things gleaned from internet search solutions, I downgraded to IE 8.

Everywhere I look I see the same problems mentioned that I'm having, and the problems have obviously been going on for several years with ie8/9. IE 8 just quits working and ask if I want Windows to check for a solution.

Any clues?

Comment: Are there any events in the Windows event logs that might add some info?

Comment: Is there a good reason for you to use IE at all? IE family are very hard for developers to deal with because it is full of special cases that change with every version (that can cost 50% more development time) and many just give up. So unless you have a good reason to do so, migrate to Firefox, Chrome, Opera or Safari.

Comment: Virus and Malware free? What AV/AM are you using? Any plug-ins?

Comment: @PPC - i wouldn't consider Safari 'backwards compatible' in the slightest, but the others are a good shout :)

Comment: Been using W7 64 bit with IE9 for a while with no issues, did you do an IE reset?

Comment: Please describe which problems you are having.

Comment: @PPC - Stop spreading that complete and total bull.  A website viewed in IE9 would look nearly identical in Firefox without any special cases.  Don't blame the idiot user for stupid computer problems.

Comment: @Ramhound: no edit war here, but I stick to it: IE special cases cost at least 25% more web integration time. Not blaming any user for that

Comment: No malware or viruses that I can find. Using Comodo AV and firewall, StopZilla, and PCTools AV Free. Java plug-in, MS Office document cache handler, and Adobe Flash Object are the only add-ons. I'll do the safe mode check and see about those. Also will try the Firefox browser. thanks

Comment: @PPC "because it is full of special cases" Can please provide a few examples? Not saying it's better or worse I'm just not going to accept what you say over my and others experiences with IE9 (which has been quite pleasant).

Comment: The best option to IE-9 to go alternate Google CHrome which is light, fast and much bug free.....

Comment: @Renan.. specifically, I get a window that says Internet Explorer is not responding. Then gives me the choices of 1) closing the program, 2) having Windows try to find and fix the problem, then reopen the page, or 3) have windows try to find the problem and close the program. It doesn't much matter which option I choose, IE is going to close regardless. Sometimes it might be in the middle of my typing, as in ths message. It happens mostly on Yahoo and Kitco, and other news sites. Edit...it happened this time, too, just after I clicked on "add comment"

Comment: I'm going to open in safe mode and reinstall IE9 and work with that for awhile. We'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This might be some add-on that is causing the problem.

I suggest you upgrade back to IE9 and [Run Internet Explorer 9 Without Addons In Safe Mode](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-internet-explorer-9-without-addons-in-safe-mode/), to see if this is indeed the case.

Answer (score -1):

You should test installing Firefox, and see if you get more or less troubles with it. If you see you have a better compatibility than IE, then stick with Firefox.